# Multiple data from excel files merge into one specific csv

Tags: vba, excel

I have to merge data from multiple Excel format files into one specific CSV file. I'm new in VBA, so I really appreciate any sample code.

```
Source data from the same Excel format file:
Cell B3: <UserName>
Cell B4: <Department>
Cell B5: <Mail address>
```

*These data are 1 user per 1 file in the same format. I'd like to append these data to the one specific existing CSV file in one click by using VBA macro in an each file.

```
Output CSV(existing CSV file):
<UserName>,<Department>,<Mailaddress>
User1,Sales,user1@domain.com
User2,HR,user2@domain.com
```

....
The first row is for the header info. I need to append data from the second row.

Comment: Welcome to [so]!  Why don't you use Excel's built-in Merge functionality instead of writing your own?  If you choose to go with VBA then...

Comment: On [so], you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading "[ask]" and "[the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score -1):

If you employ the Merge Tool in Excel, or use the Power Query, you should get what you want.  In addition, try the AddIn below. This will do all kinds of copy/paste/merge tasks.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

[image]